# How to install a search engine on cassandra?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, cassandra, full-text-search

I want to search trough cassandra data. Is cqlsh enough for that? It seems I have to use some search engine to do that. Can I use solr or elastic search?
If yes, how to do? If not, what to do? How to do fulltextsearch in cassandra?

Comment: Your question is probably not enough specific. I would suggest to start it _anyhow_, and after you find a problem, come back with this problem there.

Answer (score 3):

Several possibles solution, in random order:

- use an external search engine like ElasticSearch or Solr, not recommended because you have to manage another cluster of machine and there are also data consistency issues (what if the data is persisted in C* but fails to be indexed by the search engine ? Retry strategy ?)
- use DSE Search, a tight integration (same JVM) between Cassandra and Solr, it's not free though: http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchOverview.html
- use a secondary index implementation that provide full text search, 2 candidates

  - Stratio Cassandra Lucene index: https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index
  - TupleJump Stargate core: https://github.com/tuplejump/stargate-core
- Wait for **Cassandra 3.4** (estimated release in ~ March/April 2016) that will bring SASI index that provide full text search: https://github.com/xedin/sasi/tree/3.2-readme

Answer (score 2):

You can try [cassandra lucene index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index), I am using it in a production environement for quite a while and it is really powerful, the only thing is that if you don't trust open source projects then you might go to [Datastax Enterprise](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise)